# Filter one2many with dynamic values in interface

Tags: filter, odoo-12, one2many

Take this scenario:

```py
class Model1(models.Model):
  _name = "model1"
  _description = "Model 1"

  custom_field = fields.One2many(
    'model2',
    'registration',
  )


class Model2(models.Model):
  _name = "model2"
  _description = "Model 2"

  field_name = fields.Char(
    'Field Name',
    required=True,
  )

  field_value = fields.Char(
    'Field Value',
    required=True,
  )

  registration = fields.Many2one(
    'model1',
    required=True,
  )
```

Required Output:

Filter records of `model1` in odoo tree view based on the `field_value` where `field_name="amount"`. The `field_value` should be taken input by user. `amount` is a float stored as str.

Current filter (static):

```
domain="['&',('custom_field.field_name','=','amount'),('custom_field.field_value','>','100.0')]"
```

Actual output:

Records of `model1` having `amount='20'` get filtered in above situation.(string comparison `'20'>'100.0'`). This `100.0` is to be input by user in interface.

I tried this solution from a [forum post on odoo.com "How to use dynamic values in domain filter?"](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/how-to-use-dynamic-values-in-domain-filter-17289)

Output:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fields' of null
```

Please help! Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

use for importing fields

```
from odoo import api, fields, models
```

Try this:

```
domain="['&',('field_name','=','amount'),('field_value','>','100.0')]"
```

you can also use the above domain in py.